# Reply to a specific thread

Tags: php, gmail-api

I'm trying to reply to a specific thread with Gmail API.
Here's my code:

```
$strRawMessage = "From: Firstname lastname <".$userId.">\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "To: Firstname lastname <tomail@gmail.com>\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode("Heres my test message") . "?=\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "this <b>is a test message!\r\n";

$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);
$msg->setThreadId( $threadId );

$response = $this->service->users_messages->send($userId, $msg);
```

It sends the mail to the correct mail address but won't send it to the thread specified with "threadId".

my threadId is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Sending messages documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending)

> If you're trying to send a reply and want the email to thread, make
> sure that:
>
> 1. The Subject headers match
> 2. The References and In-Reply-To headers follow the [RFC 2822 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#appendix-A.2).

Those are the parts you may be missing since you're almost correct.