# Gmail API: Include previous messages in the reply

Tags: api, email, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using Gmail API to send messages using endpoint as listed here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Using the headers `References` and `In-Reply-To` threading works perfectly. However I'm unable to get the earlier messages quoted in the reply as would happen if the reply is composed in Gmail. Is there a way to do this or if there's a workaround?

Comment: Did you make sure that the subject matches?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962805/reply-to-a-specific-thread

Comment: @ziganotschka yes, subject remains same and threading works fine, just the previous content is not included as quoted text at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go from Gmail UI to `Show original` you will see that the quotation of earlier messages is just part of the new message body:

[image]

### It is not possible to quote the previous message automatically with the Gmail API, but you can do it yourself manually.

[image]

[image]

For this you can retrieve the date from the headers and the message text the data of the previous message body, and then create manually a string that appends the `data` after `>`.

Append then this manually created string to the end of your new message body.